# Linebreaks (^^J) in \message arguments stopped working after starting to use breqn

Tags: breqn, logging

I have several `\message` commands for inserting information into the log file, and they use `^^J` for inserting line breaks in the log file. After adding `\usepackage{breqn}`, the log file now contains `^^J` instead of line breaks. The `breqn` documentation says the `^^J` is affected, but it doesn't say what to do in order to replace the functionality of `^^J` in `\message` command arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens as `breqn` makes `^` a plain character rather than the superscript char. The low-level TeX convention that (for example) `^^J` is a newline is based on having two superscript chars in a row, so this no longer works. You can save a definition in which you have the right type of `^`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\MBreak{^^J}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\message{Hello\MBreak World}

\end{document}
```